# Is there a faster/more efficient way to open GRIB files in xarray?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-xarray

I am currently working with .grib data using xarrays and I can open the datasets as shown in the xarray [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/io.html#grib-format-via-cfgrib):

```
ds_grib = xr.open_dataset("example.grib", engine="cfgrib")
```

However, for a larger dataset this process is escaling unreasonably with size. For example, for the same dataset but covering a larger time interval, while a 2mb dataset would be read almost instantly a 20mb dataset would take several minutes to load.

Is there a way to speed up this process? Or the most straightforward way would be to break the data in smaller samples and load-merge the different time intervals?

Thanks.

Comment: what's the shape of the data? Cfgrib can be very slow when the number of time-steps is very high, see here https://github.com/ecmwf/cfgrib/issues/142

Comment: Ah then that may be the case as the data covers 13 years of hourly observations for weather. Do you know any alternatives?

Comment: Yes, open an issue on GitHub (they are often very supportive) or convert the file to netcdf before importing it (using grib2netcdf)